# Using JSON file data in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, html, chart.js

pretty new to javascript.
Im trying to read a JSON file located on my localhost (http://localhost:8080/jsonData.json) and format it to be displayed using Chart.js.

Here is my JSON File:

```
[{"date": "1/02/16", "price":15.25},
{"date":"29/01/16", "price":15.35},
{"date":"28/01/16", "price":15.1}]
```

and my html file which will display the chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Chart</title>
<script src="javascript/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8080/jsonData.json", function( data ) {
    var chartjsData = [];
    var labels = [];
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        labels.push(key);
        chartjsData.push(val);
      });

    var lineChartData = {
        labels : labels,
        datasets : [{
            fillColor : "rgba(220,280,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : chartjsData
        }]
    };
    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext("2d")).Line(lineChartData);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

basically when i run it i just get a blank screen with nothing displayed so I'm guessing its something to do with how I'm parsing the file, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The JSON in that txt file is not a valid JSON object. You need to use regular quotes like so:

```
[{"date": "1/02/16", "price":15.25},
{"date":"29/01/16", "price":15.35},
{"date":"28/01/16", "price":15.1}];
```

Also you can use jQuery's `$.getJSON` function here:

```
var myJSON = $.getJSON( "example.json", function() {
  console.log( "success" );
})
```

see here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: still doesn't seem to fix the problem.. @Borna care to elaborate?

Comment: edited... let us know if it works now, sorry I didnt notice that right away

Comment: still no good, i didn't realise i had those quotes here but in my actual file they are the correct ones. i just updated the question to reflect my changes. 
Could it be that it can't access the son file in the ROOT webapp on my localhost?